# open activity from 2 different notification

Tags: android, notifications

i build notification in chat apps, and then i receive **2 notification** from **userA** and **userB**. When i click notif from userA, its open ConversationActivity between me and userA. But while conversation between me and userA still open i click notif from userB, and then what i've got is still in conversation between me and userA not with userB. This is when i build notif

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder createTypeNotif(String message, GetCntcResp contact){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Serv.this);
        String[] parts = splitMessage(message);
        if (parts.length > 1){
            if (parts[0].equals(Serv.CHAT_PROTOCOL) || parts[0].equals(Serv.LOC_PROTOCOL)){
                resultIntent = new Intent(Serv.this, ClassChat.class);
                resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                resultIntent.putExtra(ClassChat.class.getSimpleName() + ".empId", contact.getEmpId());
                resultIntent.putExtra(ClassChat.class.getSimpleName() + ".message", message);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_chat)
                        .setContentTitle("Incoming Message")
                        .setContentText("You got message from " + contact.getName());
                builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                return builder;
            }else{
                return builder;
            }
        }else{
            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Comment: resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
This is the cause

Answer (score 0):

use this flag to start your activity instead of single top.
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` 
Learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: which one should i change, i ever change SINGLE_TOP with that and is not working

Comment: remove both 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
and place the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Then try removing resultIntent.setFlags(...) all this and just start the activity with default behavior

Comment: if you mean removing line setFlags, yes its still same :'( :'(

Comment: That was the only thing that could cause the problem in your code.  Please check your manifest too if you have placed the flags in activity declaration tag.